# uinavigationcontroller warning in xcode 4.5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I did my coding in xcode-4.2 and after updating xcode-4.5.1,My app running perfectly,while clicking window to navigate it shows following error.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <learnview: 0x8876220> on <UINavigationController: 0x8866e10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I change the function from viewdidload() to viewdidappear() still its showing the same error?Please help me to solve out

Edited:

```
    -(void)goright
   {
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.5;
   transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    learnview *lview=[[learnview alloc]initWithNibName:@"learnview" bundle:nil];
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:lview animated:NO];

    [imagetim invalidate];    
    }
```

Comment: can you tell how you are adding navigationcontroller?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy ??

Comment: @ForamMukundShah via coding in appdelegate

Comment: that I know. what code snippet you have applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call This method in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`

with Animation try below Code...

```
-(void)goright
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setDuration:1.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];

    learnview *lview=[[learnview alloc]initWithNibName:@"learnview" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:lview animated:NO];

    [imagetim invalidate];    
}
```

and without Animation try this below code...

```
-(void)goright
    {

        learnview *lview=[[learnview alloc]initWithNibName:@"learnview" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:lview animated:YES];

        [imagetim invalidate];    
    }
```

try this

Comment: i think Import your this learnview again in your project bcoz system not find this file from your Tree so just try this..