# Present Modal View from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I have generated a new Tabbed Application using storyboards.

So far I have

TabBarController
 -> FirstViewController
 -> SecondViewController
 -> ModalViewController

I'm trying to open the modal view before showing the tabBarController. I added the following code on the AppDelegate.m

`showModalView` is called from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:;`

```c
- (void)showModalView
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    GSLoginViewController *loginView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];
    [loginView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And here the output I have:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ModalViewController: 0x93670d0> on 
<UITabBarController: 0x935d170> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: You can find the answer in [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this because your Appdelegate don't know that tabbarcontroller is  your root view.You should try something like this.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

and add your code accordingly.The thing is that you should let the app delegate know tabbarcontroller is the rootviewcontroller.