# viewDidLoad changing view from if statement

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have this code

```
if ([sessionOutput isEqualToString:@"valid"]) {
    LoggedInViewController *loggedin = [[LoggedInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:loggedin animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Except when it goes to change the view i get this message:

```
 Warning: Attempt to present <LoggedInViewController: 0x717fec0> on
<ViewController: 0x8a64af0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Comment: yes it is? im coding this in Xcode

Comment: That doesn't matter, really. Excerpt from the [Xcode tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info): "This tag should only be used for questions about Xcode itself, not general Mac or iOS programming topics"

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code to `viewDidAppear:`.
`<ViewController: 0x8a64af0>` haven't been added to the view hierarchy by the time `viewDidLoad:` is called.

See this question: [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)