# warning :presenting MFMailComposeViewController on MainViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, phonegap-plugins

iam getting warning :presenting `MFMailComposeViewController` on `MainViewController` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!  when i am trying to open `MFMailComposeViewController` from inappbrowser, phonegap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are getting this warning because you might have not connected MainViewController's View with the File Owner sor something like you have not made connection properly in Interface Builder.

Good Luck!

Comment: i am doing it in phonegap, not in native ios app so no need of connecting file owner's view