# Best practice for switching between UINavigationController stacks in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

In our storyboard we have multiple `UINavigationController` stacks. For example, the `LoginViewController` stack is completely separate from the `SWRevealViewController` stack.

What's the best practice for switching between them? When I press the logout button (the logout button is on the `SWRevealController` stack) and then try to present the LoginViewController stack, I get an error like this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present LoginViewController on SWRevealViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Even though I'm specifically setting `self.window.rootViewController` to the Login View Controller's `UINavigationController` in App Delegate like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Spitfire" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNavigationController"];
LoginViewController *loginVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[nav presentViewController:loginVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Is there a way I can "dismiss" the current `UINavigationController` stack and use a new one? Or maybe I shouldn't be calling this code in my app delegate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had not played with `SWRevealViewController` before your question, so my previous response was a little more generic. I've created a sample app [here](https://github.com/evandelaney/StackOverflow-19852616) that does its best to throw around as many navigation stacks as possible; I'm sure I've covered your use case.

A few things I'll draw your attention to:

1. The "main flow" from my previous answer is right smack in the middle of the storyboard; that should help orient you.
2. `SWRevealViewController.m` can be used in conjunction with Storyboards and has a very clever hack to do so, but the documentation for it is [buried in the implementation](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/blob/master/SWRevealViewController/SWRevealViewController.m#L440). It took me a while to figure out what the hell was happening, but my example app illustrates the usage (two segues, one for "front" and the other for "back", could have a third for "right").
3. The app's main flow gets completely swapped out for the alternate flow. This is by design of `SWRevealViewController`. You are essentially *switching* to an entirely new app.
4. All sub-flows that are presented modally *disrupt* the flow.
5. The author of `SWRevealViewController` has not provided `UIStoryboardSegue` subclasses for the replacement of front, rear, and right view controllers. This would be trivial to implement, but I've elected to do the swapping manually in `FHKSettingsViewController`'s implementation.
6. I repeated code and made dinky classes to make sure what I was doing was obvious.

Comment: Thanks @edelaney05! That makes sense. Presenting the new stack with a modal segue worked. To be clear though - it's "ok" if the new stack is presented by the other UINavigationController (SWReveal, in this case)? Wouldn't it be better to dismiss SWReveal and then instantiate the new UINavigationController for login? Or is that just a limitation of storyboards?

Comment: Amazing! Your sample app helps explain this all perfectly - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should wait to call presentViewController until viewDidAppear on rootViewController.

See here for more discussion: [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

call `presentViewController` from your `UINavigationcontroller's` rootviewController in `viewDidAppear:` method

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   LoginViewController *loginVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
   [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:NO completion:nil];
   [super viewDidAppear:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is not the right place to present a view controller. `viewDidLoad` only indicates the view has been instantiated not that it is part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Not my favorite answer, but I've removed down vote now that it will technically work. :o)