# How do I segue to a scene a few layers into a navigation controller stack?

Tags: ios, swift

I had to add a navigation controller to my app so that I could use the left drawer menu (using SWRevealViewController) but its messing up my segues. My initial design had a login screen that segued to one of 4 different scenes depending on an a status indicator.

Now that I had to add a navigation controller it looks like i'll have to take the user sequentially through through each screen in the stack until they reach the relevant one. Is there a way I can jump past the first screen or 2? Or a way to not show them as I navigate through.

I tried putting the performSegue in the viewWillLoad delegate method but the screen still loads before segueing to the next scene.

Comment: so you want to present a not first view controller in your navigation stack ?

Comment: Yeah, i guess. If I have view controllers A B C D, instead of going A -> B -> C -> D I want to go directly  A -> D

Comment: look into storybaord ID for presenting/pushing the view controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Storyboard IDs to all View/Navigation Controllers that will eventually be pushed:

[image: Storyboard ID]

Now to push the desired view it depends whether your **current** View Controller stands: within or outside the Navigation Controller's stack:

### If your VC is already in the Navigation Controller stack

From your current `ViewController` push the desired view:

```
if let myViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as? MyViewControllerClassName {
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Note: `as? MyViewControllerClassName` is only required if your View Controller's class is not the default `UIViewController` but a custom one that extends it instead.

### If your VC is NOT in the Navigation Controller stack

Same principle apply, only this time you need to push the Navigation Controller itself before pushing the desired View Controller:

```
if let newNavController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNavigationController") as? UINavigationController {
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = newNavController

    // Now push the desired VC as the example above, only this time your reference to your nav controller is different
    if let myViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as? MyViewControllerClassName {
         newNavController.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: So if have view controllers A | B C D where the navigation controller starts at B can I use the method you described? Or do I need to already be in the navigation stack?

Comment: @Chris That code works from B forward. i.e. From B you want to display D. If you're at A, which is **not** in the Navigation Controller stack, it's a bit different. I'll update the answer showing both cases, hang on.

Comment: @Chris updated the answer, please take a look. I believe that's what you need.

Comment: Awesome, that works thanks so much! Although I realized I have an additional problem... Since I want to use the SWRevealViewController for my left drawer menu that actually goes between VCs A and B. So really what I have is: A (SWReveal) (NavController) B C D. Don't suppose you know how to handle that case?

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately no I haven't worked with SWReveal before, but looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860459/2752041) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25424456/2752041) answer might help you out :)