# iOS 14 green dot notification light always visible after accessing camera in flutter multi_image_picker 4.7.14

Tags: flutter, camera, ios14, imagepicker

with multi_image_picker flutter first, I select to choose a picture. Then my camera is starting the green dot is showing it's fine. But after choosing an image it should be invisible. It is still visible then the entire application. How I can resolve this in flutter? please give me some suggestions to get rid of this.

[image]

Comment: I face the same problem. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Not yet. :( If you will find answer please share here

Comment: I stopped “enableCamera: true” (it’s false by default) and the green-dot problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate Photos or PhotoKit native frameworks more precisely.

I'm not sure about your specific use case, but it seems the solution might be similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746800/7599955)

```
[self.captureSession stopRunning];
[self.previewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
self.previewLayer = nil;
self.captureSession = nil;
```