# Present ViewController Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my storyboard, I have two UIViewControllers. The initial view controller is a loading/splash screen that shows a simple image. The second view controller is a UIWebView.

I am trying to replace the loading view controller with the UIWebView view controller after the app fully loads.

Inside my loading view controller, I have this code to present the UIWebView:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^(void){}];
```

However, this code throws the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <WebController: 0x145617960> on <LoadingController: 0x145610c40> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Maybe this is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If your block of code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^(void){}];
```

is in a method of you loading view controller that is called when when the view controller is loaded such as `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear:`, or any similar methods, the problem is because your web view controller has nothing to present, as `self` in `presentViewController` refers to the loading view controller. My suggestion would be to put it in the `viewDidAppear:` of your loading view controller and dispatch after a second to ensure your loading view controller is actually capable of presenting it

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:^(void){}];
});
```