# Attempt to present controller view whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am getting this console log when running my game with a newly inserted segue between two controller views. The game works perfectly but this log keeps repeating itself many times a second.

```
2015-02-10 14:58:31.496 TestGame[64786:7741533] Warning: Attempt to 
present <TestGame.SecondViewController: 0x7f86615fa0d0> on 
<TestGame.GameViewController: 0x7f865b60dff0> whose view is not in the
window hierarchy!
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it anything to be concerned about?

**EDIT** The log starts happening as soon as my second view controller (game over screen) is called when a collision is detected:

```
func collision(Bee:SKSpriteNode, Player:SKSpriteNode) {
    self.viewController.gameOver()
}
```

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy

Comment: Thanks I actually had referred to this previously and still can't figure it out

Comment: Can you show the code of game over function

Answer (score 0):

From the code you supplied it looks like you might be handling your own collision logic. That means there is a chance that game over could be called every loop and I am guessing that triggers a segue. I would try throwing a log in collision and see if I gets called more times than you expect.

Hope that helps.