# Attempt to present View Controller Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have the following ViewControllers that present the next ViewController when something is finished:

Nr1: My GameViewController checks that the game has finished and call CheckGameFinished:

```
-(void) checkGameFinished {
if ([self.gameModel isGameOver]) {

    double delayTimeInSeconds = 3.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTimeDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayTimeInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTimeDelay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [progressBarTimer invalidate];

    level2ViewController *govc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"level2ViewController"];

    [self.finishAudio play];

    [self presentViewController:govc animated:NO completion:^(){
        [self.gameModel clearGameData];

    }];
          });
}
}
```

Then level2ViewController appears:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

double delayTimeInSeconds = 2;
dispatch_time_t popTimeDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayTimeInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTimeDelay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){


    GameViewController *gvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameViewController"];

    [self presentViewController:gvc animated:NO completion:nil];


});

}
```

and called the next ViewController, and so on.

Now I get overtime the following Warnings:

> Warning: Attempt to present GameViewController on level2ViewController
>   whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: possible duplicate of [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Comment: Are you creating new view controllers forever?  `GameViewController` instantiates a `level2ViewController` which instantiates a `GameViewController` which....

Comment: the view controller is in my storyboard, and i want just to call them without segues

Comment: The view controller is in memory; its **description** is in the storyboard.  Every time you call "instantiate..." you create a new one.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for this Information. So how can i "repair" My Problem? Dealloc After calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't present a view controller from `viewDidLoad`, instead call from `viewDidAppear:`. Also using `dispatch_after` like that (assuming you are using it to hopefully make sure the view is on screen and not for gaming purposes) is a very bad practice.
When the view controller that is being loaded has done being presented (that happens when `viewDidAppear:` is called) you can present a different one:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    GameViewController *gvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:gvc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: but in my game i can't call it from viewdidappear. i want to call it when the method CheckGameFinished was called... For the other view controller it is working as intended, thanks

Comment: I was referring to your 2nd piece of code which tries to present a view controller from `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Glad it worked, if the answer solved your problem please consider marking the green check for the answer, thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this when my `segue` type was `modal`, changing to `push` fixed it for me