# Cannot transition

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, I've been playing around with Sprite Kit and Swift stuff, and I was trying to transition between a game scene and a regular UIVewController when I encountered an issue. It returns an error when the actual program is run. Here is my code:

```
var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main.storyboard", bundle: nil)
var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("menu") as! UIViewController
self.view!.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is the error:

```
Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle //bundle location here... (irrelevant)
```

Does anybody know why this isn't working? When I look at the view on the left of the screen, I see that the storyboard file's name is "Main.storyboard". Did I do something blatantly wrong?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean '"transition between a game scene and a regular UIViewController"? A `UIViewController` contains an `SKView` which contains an `SKScene`...

Comment: my UIViewController does not contain an SKView

Comment: How are you displaying your `SKScene` then? You need an `SKView` to present an `SKScene`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. I am presenting a menu scene--which is a UIViewController--from an SKScene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the storyboard is simply `"Main"` instead of `"Main.storyboard"`.
From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:):

> The name of the storyboard resource file without the filename extension. This method raises an exception if this parameter is nil.

Comment: well, now it says that the view is not in the window heirarchy

Comment: If you want to present a new viewcontroller, just use self.presentViewController... instead of your last line.

Comment: that does not work because self refers to an SKScene, not a UIViewController

Comment: I would suggest you to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320222/2592349