# Objective-C to Swift: "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am developing an iOS application using Objective-C and I want to use a Swift class (Alert box). I implement the whole function. Without any error I can pass the values. But I am getting the following error message:

```
"whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"
```

**I've tried different ways:**

Method 1

```
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Method 2

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Method 3

```
var mainView:MainViewController = MainViewController()
mainView.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

All methods are resulting the same error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Comment: show you code for alertController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my self I found the answer for this question.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController,animated: true, completion: nil)
```