# Image picking doesn't work in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I have UIWebView within one of tab of UINavigationController. Webpage has image uploader built in, when I click it it opens menu where I can take a photo or select from library, but no matter what i choose it disappears, web view goes to homepage and console throws an error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x14c56600> on <UINavigationController: 0x15407a00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

So I created another empty project and placed UIWebView directly in first view of Main.storyboard and it worked just fine. What can I do to make this work in a tab?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) relates to your question, check it out and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes I was trying multiple of those functions like viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews but none of them was working. Another thing I found was to set it as rootViewController but looks like there is no anything like self.window.rootViewController perhaps it was in some older versions.