# Swift - Elements missing when programmatically instantiating a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

First of all, I'm brand new to swift and iOS dev! I've decided to get started with it, and so far so good. Except for today.
So I first created a single view app, following the tuto, then I decided to see what happens if a added another view. Using segue to navigate between views seemed to work fine, so I wanted to see how I could navigate programmatically, having in mind that the "destination view" may be conditional on more than just a user pressing a button. So I added a first view to become my initial view controller, and I've found the following code online to transition to my other view:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home")
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:false, completion:nil)
```

There was no problem, no error or console message, except for one little problem: some UI elements of the "destination view" (nextViewController in my case) are missing when the view loads! And some of them (but not all) show up after I click on some other elements of the view.. Note that there was/is no problem if I set the nextViewController as the initial one.
I haven't been able to find any clue on the internet about that problem, and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction..

Comment: Please provide your nextViewController class code, we can't tell what is going wrong without it

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, 5 more minutes and finally an error message were enough to fix that problem!
I've found my solution on the following thread:
[whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)
As it's said, moving my code from the viewDidLoad method to the viewDidAppear one fixed the issue. And I had the same error as the OP mentioned.