# Display Alert Message from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I want to display a alert message from `viewDidLoad()` method of `ViewController.m` instead from `viewDidAppear()` method.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //A SIMPLE ALERT DIALOG
    UIAlertController *alert =   [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                              message:@"Enter User Credentials"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                               }];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"OK action");
                           }];

    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    [alert addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and I am getting this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present `<UIAlertController: 0x7fbc58448960>` on `<ViewController: 0x7fbc585a09d0>` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy)

Comment: @Woodstock my question is different...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK not a bug, the issue is that in `viewDidLoad` the view hierarchy is not fully set. If you use `viewDidAppear`, then the hierarchy is set.

**If you really want to call this alert in `viewDidLoad` you can do so by wrapping your presentation call in this GCD block to cause a slight delay, waiting for the next run loop, however I suggest you don't (it's ugly).**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: my pleasure, just a note, that although the above works, I guess Apple didn't intent the alerts to be presented in viewDidLoad, because it's very early in the viewController lifecycle.

Comment: Great answer Woodstock! Thank you for the feedback saving my day :)

Answer (score 10):

to move this call to the viewDidAppear: method.

Comment: you're right, I think this should be callable from viewDidLoad though.

Comment: but i want to call form viewDidLoad : method

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed a navigation controller and present the controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  //A SIMPLE ALERT DIALOG


   UIAlertController *alert =   [UIAlertController
                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                          message:@"Enter User Credentials"
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


   UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                           }];

   UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                       actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                       {
                           NSLog(@"OK action");
                       }];

   [alert addAction:cancelAction];
   [alert addAction:okAction];

   [self.navigationController presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
   //    [self presentViewController:cameraView animated:NO completion:nil]; //this will cause view is not in the window hierarchy error

}
```

**OR**

```
  [self.view addSubview:alert.view];
  [self addChildViewController:alert];
  [alert didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: i try your suggested code. but app is crashed when I click on any button i.e OK , Cancel.. and also Alert Box is displayed on top-left side

Comment: @ShivaniArorra i have updated my ans check this you need to do `[self.navigationController presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];`

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3 iOS 10, I used operation queue to put the block of code that updates the UI onto the main thread.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

var opQueue = OperationQueue()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "MESSAGE", message: "HELLO WORLD!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        // add an action (button, we can add more than 1 buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        // show the alert
        self.opQueue.addOperation {
            // Put queue to the main thread which will update the UI
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

In short we are using async. This allows the alert message to be displayed as expected (even when we are in viewDidLoad()).

Comment: This is actually adding a block to a local operation queue that adds another block to the main operation queue that then presents the alert. It's more normal to use a dispatch queue for this: `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`.