# Application doesn't show Alert View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I've got an application that should open an Alert View Controller in the viewDidLoad()-function. It's a simple reminder app. Here's the piece of code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Reminder", message: "Your reminder text", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sure!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (finished) in
        self.didReceiveRemoteNotificationAction()
    })
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But the problem is: it doesn't show up! Can anyone explain to me why?

I do know that my Storyboard is very... interleaved with views. But that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `viewDidLoad` is triggered, the view controller's view is not in the window hierarchy yet, and this is why your alert is not being presented.

You should put your alert presentation code inside `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692351/4763963) talks about the same problem and explains an alternative option that uses GCD.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320222/4763963) has a good discussion about `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're calling it from the ViewDidLoad, your views are not set yet! You have two options:

- Call it from ViewDidAppear (suggested).
- Call it using GCD thread :

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }