# Trying to present UIViewController fails with error "view is not in the window hierarchy"

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to present a UIViewController from the Storyboard (no UINavigationController here)

When I start my app, I print out:

```
print("self.view.window.rootViewController : \(UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.rootViewController)")
print("self : \(self)")
```

Output:

```
self.view.window.rootViewController : Optional(<NewProject.MainViewController: 0x7f95d0d8bcc0>)
self : <NewProject.MainViewController: 0x7f95d0d8bcc0>
```

My `MainViewController` is indeed the `rootViewController`. Good!

Then I want to present another `UIViewController` and I do:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("testViewController") as! TestViewController

presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And I get an error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <NewProject.testViewController: 0x7f95d0d92a20> 
on <NewProject.MainViewController: 0x7f95d0d8bcc0> whose view 
is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What's wrong? I'm trying to present a view controller from the root view controller.

Comment: is the window that MainViewController is in the key window?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320222/4475605

Comment: @WillM. No, it's set to false. I guess that's the problem?

Comment: @AdrianB, thanks for the link, indeed I'm calling it from `viewDidLoad`. The problem is that I don't want to call it in `viewDidAppear` as I don't want to show this viewController if some conditions are gathered.

Comment: @Nico for what reason can you not put it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Because on my first view controller, I'm checking whether or not the user is already logged in. If he is, I don't want to show the login view. I guess it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: I'll probably do the checking in the AppDelegate and choose the rootViewController from there.