# wkwebview not showing anything but a white screen

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I am trying to show a `WKWebView` over another view using the `presentViewController` method but only shows a white screen.

I have implemented the WKWebView in my `ViewController.m` as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
  _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                                 configuration:configuration];
  _webView.navigationDelegate = self;
  [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
  [self.view addSubview:_webView];
}
```

then in another class I have a method with the following code:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ViewController *webView1 =[[ViewController alloc] init];

[delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController: webView1 
                                                 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This last code "presents" a white screen on top of my `rootViewController`. I have no clue of why my webView is a white screen.

Comment: You might want to check your URL to make sure the request is valid. Also, make sure that you are using HTTPS in the url or that you have disabled/set the appropriate values for ATS in the plist file. ATS is enabled by default so if you are not using the HTTPS protocol the request will  be blocked.

Comment: @dkw5877 I double checked. I am using HTTPS in my link: `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://github.com"];`

Comment: Are you calling the `presentViewController ` method in `viewDidLoad`? If so, try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) and see if that helps.

Comment: @dkw5877 I am calling it on a separate class, `presentViewController` works correctly, it covers my root view with my webview but it only displays a white screen.

Comment: Why ViewController *webView1 =[[ViewController alloc] init];
you are not  using  storyboard or xib ?

Comment: @PKT `WKWebView` its not available there. It can only be used programatically as far as I know.

Comment: @AndresC.Viesca my point is your view controller does not contain any xib or storyboard reference ?

Comment: @PKT No, I did not think I needed one.

Comment: ya it needed to check that, set background color of your view where you are added webview and also check background color from where you are presenting view controller

Comment: is viewDidLoad Methods is called ?

Comment: @AndresC.Viesca in the class where you are presenting the webview1 controller, in what method are you calling presentViewController?

Comment: @PKT I verified it, it is being called. I can visually see how the web view is presented with an animation.

Comment: @dkw5877 it is a custom class with custom methods.

Comment: implement delegate method - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
} see there

Answer (score 2):

What URL are you loading?

It might be that you need to add to your plist file permissions to load a non-secure URL.

Add this to your plist and see if that works.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

For more info, see here:
https://ooiks.com/2017/10/15/ios-wkwebview-return-a-blank-screen-white-screen/

Also make sure that the URL you are trying uses HTTP or HTTPS. Make sure that `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url : URL(string: yourURLString))` returns `true` for your URL.

Answer (score -2):

So, I found why it was just showing a white screen. Turns out that you have to wrap the `WKWebView` with a `UINavigationController`.

By adding:

```
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: _webView];
```

to my custom method in my custom class and then present the `controller`  I just created instead of the `_webView`:

```
 [delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController: controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Works fine now.

Comment: You don't "have to wrap the WKWebview" with a UINavigationController.  Mine is working without a navigation controller.