# SFSafariViewController not in window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am trying to integrate google login inside my IOS APP (with Swift), but every time I run it I get the following `warning/error`:

> [10061:521185] Warning: Attempt to present UITabBarController:
>   0x7db35400 on SFSafariViewController: 0x7b60a2a0 whose view is not in
>   the window hierarchy!

Does anybody knows how this can be fix? What's the reason it hasn't loaded yet the Safari controller view?

Thank You very much in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: SFSafariViewController is its own separate process and does not show up in the window hierarchy.

Comment: But then, is there any solution to avoid getting the warning?

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to present a UITabBarController on SFSafariController - that is not possible. Try removing the UITabBarController you are trying to present from the Safari View Controller.

Comment: @user3149877 Please show your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

This happens because the SFSafariViewController's view is not in the window's view hierarchy at the point that it has been loaded. Maybe you are using the viewDidLoad() to present it. Use instead viewDidAppear()