# How to Navigate between Viewcontrollers without any action from user swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 2 view controllers and want to navigate from first one to the second without any user interaction but based on variable came from http request

Edit:-
1- I tried to use segue like this:                             self.performSegueWithIdentifier("updateuser", sender:nil)
 but it return no segue with identifier 'updateuser

2- i want to create navigation based on my variable without any user interaction

//first Viewcontroller

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mapViewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("update") as? hhViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObj!, animated: true)
}
```

}

//second viewcontroller

class hhViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EsCJ.png)

Comment: i tried to use segue 
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("updateuser", sender:nil)

 but it return for me not identifier

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41887007/5461400

Comment: @AmalKhaled have you tried some thing

Comment: thanks but i want to create seque not based on any action from user it move to another controller based on my variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u do not require a segue for this. U can just push navigation Controller.

let storyBoardHome = UIStoryboard(name:storyBoardName, bundle: nil)

```
 let 1stViewController = storyBoardHome.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: <1stViewControllerID>)


let 2ndViewController = storyBoardHome .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 2ndViewControllerID) 


self.navigationController?.pushViewController(1stViewController/2ndViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: May be because u have not implemented any UI for that viewController..try putting break point in view did load.

Comment: i  changed back ground color and it changed but it doesn't present view already exist in the storyboard

Comment: Not getting this scenario.. It would be nice if u share the code in ur viewController

Comment: i tried to create sample but to gives me an error please see edited post

Comment: So u want to navigate to hhViewController from ViewContoller right?

Comment: Actually the identifier "update" u have given is for segue. Give a storyBoardId which u find in identity inspector of viewController and use that    when u push

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically in Swift3..I am not sure but you can try this in your function where you getting your variable value.

```
if var == "variablevalue" {
     navigationController?.pushViewController(FirstController(), animated: true)
} else {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondController(), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: If you didn't add any functionality in your viewDidload it will show you black view which is default. If you want to check your viewDidload working or not just change your background view color by doing - view.backgroundColor = .red

Comment: i tried to change back ground color and it changed but it doesn't present view already exist in the storyboard

Comment: I am not storyboard type I do stuff programmatically..i found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41095699/5891662 it might help you