# switch to view controller from GameScene.swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a View Controller called "MenuVC" in my Main.Storyboard file. I want to show this View Controller programmatically from my GameScene.swift file.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in GameScene.swift file:

```
//...
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuVC") as! MenuVC
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
//...
```

But here is the full answer: [Swift programmatically navigate to another view controller/scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450124/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene)

Answer (score 0):

First set the view controller storyboard id in storyboard.

[image]

And then

```
let menuVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuVC" as! MenuVC
```

And if you are using navigation controller

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(menuVC, animated: true)
```

Or you can present it.

```
self.present(menuVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```