# Navigate from a ViewController to an another on didSelectRowAt programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a custom `UITableView`. The table has a custom `UITableViewCell` too.

How to navigate from the first `ViewController`  to an another when you select/click one of the rows?

## Note

I have not used `StoryBoard`.

## Update

This my code. Each one of the classes are external file. Let me know, if you need more code.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(testTableView)
    }

    let testTableView: TestTableView = {
        let table = TestTableView()
        table.register(TestTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TestTableViewCell.identifier)
        return table
    }()
}

class TestTableView: UITableView,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TestTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}



class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier  = "testCell"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift programmatically navigate to another view controller/scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450124/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene)

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: @MoAbdul-Hameed How do you select row from the controller?

Comment: @mahan You need to make your current view controller (the one that contains the table view) conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and implement its `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Added some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete answer:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let newViewController = NewViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You don't call this method, it is a delegate method. You need to set the delegate of your table view to be your first view controller. In `viewDidLoad` add: `self.tableView.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 1):

In `UIKit` in order to programmatically navigate from `TableCell` you can do it without storyboard.
You have two ways to view next `viewController`

1. **If you want to present .......**

animating from bottom to top
(one thing to remember) you can not present new view without dismissing previous presented screen, otherwise app crash due to conflict of presented  screen

```
yourTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)//used for single Tap
let vC = YourViewController (nibName: "" , bundle : nil)
        vC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //this line is optional for fullscreen
        self.present(vC, animated: true , completion: nil)
```

2. **Or if you want to View your viewController normally (2 is batter) ....**

animate from right to left

```
yourTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
let vC = YourViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     let vc = yourCustomVCName (nibName: "yourCustomVC nibName" , bundle : nil)
     self.present(vc, animated: true , completion: nil)  
}
```