# Why does View Controller Shift in Storyboard on Button Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

I am new to IOS App development and have a question. I'm trying to segue from one view controller to another. However, it seems that every time I ctrl+drag from the options button to the adjacent view controller and choose the 'show' option, the view controller "shifts" down(bottom picture). Why does that happen and if it is not the correct behavior, how can I do it right? Thanks!

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Select your `ViewController` and check `Top Bar` property in Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set fullscreen style manually if select model style,
a fullscreen option did not show in **Push** type, you must use Navigation Controller if you want to set **fullscreen** for **Push** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg20Y.png

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the segue(the line that connects view controllers) and open the Attribute Inspector in right panel, you will see the `Kind` is set to `Present Modally`. This means your view controller will popup on your current screen.

You can change the `Kind` to `Push` and it will start showing normally.

Also embed your controller in a navigation Controller

**Option 2**

If you dont want a navigation controller, you can also change the presentation to full screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**If you're new to iOS**

then I might suggest don't use `show` and don't use `segue` from storyboard

If you don't know the concept of navigation controller (`push` and `pop` methods), then have a look at it (You may not use `show` afterwards)

have a look at following link

[Swift programmatically navigate to another view controller/scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450124/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene)