# Swfit 3 FBSDKCoreKit error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, fbsdk

Good Day guys
Seems I can't solve this problem so I really need help.

When I import the FBSDKCoreKit I got this 21 multiple errors and I can't proceed in implementing the login. I got tried different methods from searching but it seems it wouldn't work with my problem. The image below would explain it.

[image: help]

Hoping for your positive response. Thank you! :D

Comment: Can you provide podfile data ?

Comment: Can you explain more what you trying to do ?

Comment: @BhupatBheda thanks for the reply. I'm trying to implement the facebook sdk framework in my project. I cannot go through with the tutorials because i got this error.

Comment: @Ankitchauhan I'd just include pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit' and pod install and there is no problem. The problem comes when I import the library

Comment: did you check which version of cocoapod you are using? and can you tell me which swift version you are doing?

Comment: @BhupatBheda its /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods.rb

Comment: @BhupatBheda I'm using swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: @broadfire016 please refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616714/i-am-trying-login-with-facebook-it-succeeds-at-login-but-do-not-return-to-app/39617161#39617161

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the pod file. 
1. Remove the facebook pods from your pod file
2. Clean the project
3. Empty the derived data folder of your Xcode
4. Buld the project
5. Add the facebook pod files -> pod 'FacebookCore  pod 'FacebookLogin' pod'FacebookShare'
6. Then import facebook file in AppDelegate class

If problem persists try creating a dummy project and install Facebook pods. You will get the idea what is missing.

Comment: This worked for me, see more info from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Add FBIntegrationWithSwift-Bridging-Header (Objective C to Swift Wrapper).

If you have no idea about "How to add a bridging header?" refer the following blog.

[Integrate Objective-C file in Swift](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-objective-c-file-swift)
Import FBSDK Login and Core Kit

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Facebooks Swift SDK because there is one for iOS too and it is based on Objective-C.

If you did, how did you open the xcode workspace file instead of the xcode project file (this file wont work after using Podfile)

If you working with the workspace file and it is not working try to reinstall the podfile(first uninstall it, there is a tool for that not sure about the name found it on stack overflow). If it is still not woking its probably not because of Facebooks SDK or Podfile something in your code is not write