# Performing segue after dismissing modal swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

So I'm pushing a side menu onto my root menu using a modal segue and then attempting to dismiss the side menu that only covers half the page and performing the segue from the root vc when a button is pressed in the side menu. It either returns; recivere has no sague with identifier, or warning: attempt to perform segue that is not in window hierarchy.

```
func SubmitSettingPressed (sender: UIButton){

    let mainView = MainViewController()

    dismiss(animated: true) {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController
        vc?.ToSubmition()
    }
```

then in the root vc

```
func ToSubmition(){
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSubmition", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: This func SubmitSettingPressed is on the modal viewController?

Comment: @Sina   Go to Main.storyboard and assign this ID `MainViewController` in the attributes inspector to MainViewController  http://imgur.com/a/CvFj0

Comment: @JoséNeto yah the SubmitSettingPressed is on the modal VC

Comment: @bibscy changing the ID prevents the app from crashing but I still get this error -  Warning: Attempt to present <SideMenu.UISideMenuNavigationController: 0x7fabe3168a00> on <Happening.MainViewController: 0x7fabe2483fb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: @Sina I am not sure what it's causing the error, but you might find this answer helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883