# Attempt to present....whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift3

I have been battling to get this to work. I have written a function to try and check if the user is logged in or not and if they are not they will be presented with a login screen but I keep getting an error that the Attempt to present....whose view is not in the window hierarchy! and it displays the default storyboard, here is the code below

```
func checkuser () {
    let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    if currentUser != nil {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventsstoryboard")
        print("user logged in")
    }   
    else
    {

        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc") as! loginviewcontroller
        self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("user not logged in")

    }
}
checkuser()
```

Comment: from where you are calling the function checkuser?

Comment: refer the answer to the question below
[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to present UIViewController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the)

Comment: if you're trying this while the view is loading, you should move it to viewDidAppear

Comment: im am calling the function in the viewdidload section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your if-part,
are you presenting your viewController as:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventsstoryboard") as! someviewcontroller
self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)
print("user logged in")
```

Comment: thanks all got it working using the below method. used viewdidappear and it solved it.

Comment: if you find my answer helpful, kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks all got it working using the below method. used viewdidappear and it solved it

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    func checkuser () {
        let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        if currentUser != nil
        {
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventsstoryboard")
            print("user logged in")
        }

        else
        {

            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc") as! loginviewcontroller
            self.present(vc,animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("user not logged in")

        }
    }
    checkuser()

}
```