# Segue is not performed

Tags: ios, swift

In my first ViewController, I am checking to see if the user is already logged in with Firebase and if he/she is, redirect to the main switchboard and if not, redirect to the login view. However, the Welcome View just stays in view and no redirect happens.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class WelcomeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: RoundedShadowButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil) {
            //user is logged in
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSwitchboardVC", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            //user in not logged in
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoginVC", sender: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnLoginWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoginVC", sender: self)
    }

}
```

CODE CHANGED

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class WelcomeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: RoundedShadowButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("AUTH USER")
        print(Auth.auth().currentUser)
        print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)

        if(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil) {
            //user is logged in
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSwitchboardVC", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            //user in not logged in
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoginVC", sender: self)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnLoginWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoginVC", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any log in message, like `Attempt to present <...> on <WelcomeVC:...> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`? If yes, because you entered `viewDidLoad()` doesn't mean that the view in present. `viewDidLoad()` means "did load in memory", no "shown on screen".

Comment: not exactly sure what you are asking

Comment: Do you have logs in debugguer console when you try that code?

Comment: LOL, I will soon

Comment: as expected, Auth.auth().currentUser is empty so the segue to LoginVC should happen

Comment: Are you seeing [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the)?

Comment: no errors at all

Comment: Try to add your code in `viewWillAppear` method instead of `viewDidLoad`, does it make any change?

Comment: I changed the code and added it to question

Comment: Divide your problem into two parts. 
1. Does Auth functionality is working or not.
2. Perform segue is working or not.

Comment: Login successful ... no segue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will not redirect to any view because you have written it in viewWillAppear. Segue cannot be performed before view appeared
So you must perform segue in viewDidAppear.
If everything else is correct (segue name and connections) then definitely it will work.

Try this -

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("AUTH USER")
    print(Auth.auth().currentUser)
    print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)

    if(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil) {
        //user is logged in
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSwitchboardVC", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        //user in not logged in
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLoginVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forgot to accept this answer, if this solves your problem.

Comment: still testing it now

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a properly connected segue in your Storyboard and that the name of the segue is correctly set to "goToLoginVC".

Also please provide the results of tapping the button that is connected to the `btnLoginWasPressed` action to verify that the segue is working in that circumstance and just not in your `viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: Segues created by dragging from yellow icon to VC and confirmed named goToLoginVC and goToSwitchboardVC. Pressing button moves app to the Login Screen