# Multiple if statements with a single performSegue

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

So I have a code which looks working fine except I see an error :

> App[0000:000000] Warning: Attempt to present <_App.nextView: 0x000000000> on <_App.PreviousView: 0x000000000> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

So I searched and I think my situation is like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708302/9455258).

Except, I need multiple segues as far as I know. So I don't know how to handle, my code is similar like this :

```
if stateNumber == 3 && !isCondition01True {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextView", sender: Any?.self)
    }
if stateNumber == 3 && !isCondition02True {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextView", sender: Any?.self)
// and like +30 more statements like this
```

Is there a workaround for like these situations? Like a code to trigger a segue once? I tried to group this statements before but I failed (I'm still learning swift, so I may have missed something).

Comment: Use `else if`, not only `if`. And I guess that it's in a preference order.

Comment: where you put this code

Comment: Unrelated but what is `Any?.self` supposed to be? And please post more meaningful code. Your example will perform the same segue which can be checked with **one** if statement.

Comment: guys. he just calling same segue many times. more than one if clause succeeds.

Comment: PS: The error/warning is not related to the question about multiple if statements

Comment: @vadian , I'm using `Any?.self` for a while, otherwise my segues won't work. If I'm not mistaken, adding `.self` was Xcode's own suggestion. (I create those segues between storyboard's viewcontrollers). And I'm using multiple if's because this is a game, there are multiple situations (which are not connected each other) which led to "game lost" screen.

Comment: @hasan , exactly

Comment: The `sender` parameter is supposed to be an **instance** (not a type) like `self` or `stateNumber` or ***no sender*** is  `nil`. Nothing else. `Any?.self` is hilarious but pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `else` or you can try to combine them as following:

```
if stateNumber == 3 {
    if !isCondition01True || !isCondition02True {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextView", sender: Any?.self)
    }
}
```

etc ...

Comment: include all the 30+ if(s) in the question. I can combine them for you fast.

Comment: ok, this should work (logically), I'll try when I find a chance.