# I presented firebase AuthViewController in viewDidLoad and getting this error. What's the reason?

Tags: swift, firebase, viewdidload, viewdidappear

> Warning: Attempt to present 
>   on  whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

I presented firebase `AuthViewController` in `viewDidLoad` and getting this error. But when I present that `AuthViewController` by a button click or in `viewDidAppear`, it works perfect.

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the

Comment: Thnx for the answer, works for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to present UIViewController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the)

Comment: It's probably a coding issue but since the code was not included in the question, it would be hard to determine the specific cause. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)