# Not able to present a viewController which is inside Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am facing a serious issue. I have a framework named "abc.framework" and it contains a function in which you can pass a viewController object.

```
//this is the method in my framework 

func launchView(view:UIViewController){

}

//this is what needs to be written on App side

myFrameworkFile.launchView(view: self)
```

The above method is used to present the Framework's viewcontroller i.e abc.framework viewController on top of the the viewController object passed. The launch method contains the following code :

```
func launchView(view:UIViewController)
{


var rootController: UIViewController?

    rootController = view

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "abcFrameworkBundle.bundle/abcUIMain", bundle: nil)
    let VC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "selectedviewcontroller") as! SelectedViewController

    rootController?.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

From the above method the viewController the SelectedViewController viewDidLoad method is getting called however it is not getting presented and I am getting the below warning

> Warning: Attempt to present  on 
>   whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the) help you? Anyway, I would create static method inside your framework class which would return me instance of controller. So then you could just do in your project `let controller = SomeClass.instantiate(); present(controller, animated: true)`

Comment: where you are calling this method "launchView" ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call this method `myFrameworkFile.launchView(view: self)` in `viewDidLoad` or earlier. Try to move it inside `viewDidAppear`