# Warning: Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm getting the error when I try to click on the share button. I've put breakpoints into the first line of the On_Share method & they're not being hit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to present UIViewController on UIViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/attempt-to-present-uiviewcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the)

Comment: please add some code. Your question is incomplete - you simply say you try to press some button (what button, what is happening when it is pressed? we don't know it), and then you tell us that some breakopint in some method is not hit. We are not wizards - we can't tell you what is wrong without seing code!

Comment: I am using "plugin.share" plugin and code is simple one line code "await CrossShare.Current.Share(Message, null);".and button means when we click on share button.

Comment: Does the view controller has a navigationBar? Need more code!