# Attempt to present Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_NavigationRenderer whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, qlpreviewcontroller

Hello guys I got this issue:
Attempt to present  on  
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
Someone knows how to create a UINavigationController to open
a PDF File in iOS
I create the Dependecy Service for Android and iOS but only 
worked in Android and iOS somethings the PDF appears and somethings not
I tried searching a way to implement with UIViewController but not works
This is the class

```
public class SaveFile : ISaveFile
{

    public async Task<string> SaveFiles(string filename, byte[] bytes)
    {

        try
        {
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);

            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
            OpenPDF(filePath);
            //OpenFile(filePath);
            return filePath;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            return "";
        }
    }

    public  void OpenPDF(string filePath)
    {
          FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

        QLPreviewController previewController = new QLPreviewController();


        previewController.DataSource = new PDFPreviewControllerDataSource(fi.FullName, fi.Name);

        //UIView uIView = previewController.View;
             UINavigationController controller = FindNavigationController();
        controller.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
        if (controller != null)

                  controller.PresentViewController(previewController, true,null);


    }

    /*
    public void OpenFile(string filePath)
    {
        var viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath));
        var controller = GetVisibleViewController();
        viewer.PresentOpenInMenu(controller.View.Frame, controller.View, true);
    }




    //*/

    private UINavigationController FindNavigationController()
    {
        foreach (var window in UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows)
        {
            if (window.RootViewController.NavigationController != null)
                return window.RootViewController.NavigationController;
            else
            {
                UINavigationController val = CheckSubs(window.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers);
                if (val != null)
                    return val;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private UINavigationController CheckSubs(UIViewController[] controllers)
    {
        foreach (var controller in controllers)
        {
            if (controller.NavigationController != null)
                return controller.NavigationController;
            else
            {
                UINavigationController val = CheckSubs(controller.ChildViewControllers);
                if (val != null)
                    return val;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    public class PDFItem : QLPreviewItem
    {
        string title;
        string uri;

        public PDFItem(string title, string uri)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.uri = uri;
        }

        public override string ItemTitle
        {
            get { return title; }
        }

        public override NSUrl ItemUrl
        {
            get { return NSUrl.FromFilename(uri); }
        }


    }

    public class PDFPreviewControllerDataSource : QLPreviewControllerDataSource
    {
        string url = "";
        string filename = "";

        public PDFPreviewControllerDataSource(string url, string filename)
        {
            this.url = url;
            this.filename = filename;
        }

        public override IQLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, nint index)
        {
            return (IQLPreviewItem)new PDFItem(filename, url);
        }

        public override nint PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller)
        {
            return 1;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: which specific line causes the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320222/10539446) to understand the error message which you get.

**Solution:**

Remove the find `FindNavigationController` methods and use `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController` to present the `QLPreviewController` :

```
   public void OpenPDF(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);

        QLPreviewController previewController = new QLPreviewController();


        previewController.DataSource = new PDFPreviewControllerDataSource(fi.FullName, fi.Name);

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);


        //UIView uIView = previewController.View;
        //UINavigationController controller = FindNavigationController();
        //controller.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
        //if (controller != null)

        //    controller.PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);


    }
```

BTW, you can also use webview to load pdf files.

Comment: And now I get this issue :Warning: Attempt to present <QLPreviewController: 0x7fc73062fa00>  on <RgPopupPlatformRenderer: 0x7fc734945370> which is already presenting <Rg_Plugins_Popup_IOS_Renderers_PopupPageRenderer: 0x7fc734944240>

Comment: Did you pop up a Rg_Plugins_Popup view before call openpdf method? Dismiss it and the present the QLPreviewController.